# Error in nls, step factor reduced below minFactor

Tags: r, nls

I have the following dataframe:

```
> dput(df_acf)
structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), y = c(1, 
0.0595936565187637, 0.0376022880804335, 0.0521100393333187, 0.0720561234389795, 
0.0262258507877819, -0.0126644770510529, 0.18604968147151, 0.115018192163521, 
-0.0476175556946567, -0.183213245514104)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

which I would like to fit using this non linear function

```
f <- function(t, coeff_sigma, coeff_alpha,coeff_omega) {
  coeff_sigma * exp(-coeff_alpha*t)*cos(coeff_omega*t)
}
```

However, when using `nls`

```
fit <- nls(y~f(x,coeff_sigma,coeff_alpha,coeff_omega), data=df_acf, start=list(coeff_sigma=0.8, coeff_alpha=0.62, coeff_omega=0.65),control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000))
```

I get this error: `error in nls, step factor reduced below minFactor`

Comment: The first point looks artificial. If you believe that point to be correct, then `coeff_sigma` should be 1. However, the data doesn't really show an inflection and sign change in the first three points as we would expect from the cosine. The last points show a strange jump. A cosine function is notoriously difficult to fit (without some mathematical magic) even with good data. Your data doesn't look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to other parametric models then this easily fits:

```
fo <- y ~ a * (1 + b * x) ^ -c
fit2 <- nls(fo, df_acf, start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1))

plot(df_acf)
lines(fitted(fit2) ~ x, df_acf, col = "red")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Using `nls2` seems to work for me at least with the `brute-force` algorithm.

```
library(nls2)
nls2(y~f(x,coeff_sigma,coeff_alpha,coeff_omega), data=df_acf, start=list(coeff_sigma=0.8, coeff_alpha=0.62, coeff_omega=0.65),control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000), algorithm = "brute-force")
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ f(x, coeff_sigma, coeff_alpha, coeff_omega)
   data: NULL
coeff_sigma coeff_alpha coeff_omega 
       0.80        0.62        0.65 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.2355

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

Comment: While this does not give an optimum I think it gives a reasonable approximation.